# Why won't the logo and button be on the same row?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to setup the logo on the top-left and the login button on the top right. Whenever I run it in my browser, they just won't stay in the same row for some reason. Why is that?

```
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>logo here</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button>login here</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you setup the demo of your current output and how you would like it to be?

Comment: Have you tried `col-sm-6` or `col-xs-6` instead of `col-md-6`?

Comment: They seem to stay in the same row in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/aWDvKa9Ehe) - unless you mean when you're viewing it at a smaller screen width, in which case j08691 has some suggestions.

Comment: @j08691 I thought the same, but I guess he wants to align them vertically. http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/tb1ez85m/ Maybe!

Comment: that xs seemed to do the trick, thank you very much!